# Object equivalency in hashCode

Tags: java, equals

I'm working with hashCode for the first time and not sure how to check if two objects are equal. This is what I have so far.

```
/** Represents a City */
class City {
/** Decimal format to print leading zeros in zip code */
static DecimalFormat zipFormat = new DecimalFormat("00000");

    int zip;
    String name;
    String state;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;


    /** The full constructor */
    public City (int zip, String name, String state, 
            double longitude, double latitude) {
            this.zip   = zip;
            this.name  = name;
            this.state = state;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.latitude  = latitude;
}

/** to make sure the two cities have the same name, state, zip code,
    * and the same latitude and longitude */
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
            City temp = (City)obj;

            System.out.println(City.equals(obj));
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: You have your answer in your javadoc there. To check if they are equal, check if their names, states, zip codes, lat, and long are equal.

Comment: @turbo You're wrong there. If two objects are equal, it is required that they have the same hash code, but if two objects have the same hash code, they may be different.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're right, deleted my comment so no one reads it and takes it as fact.

Comment: Take a look to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Assuming equality in your case means all properties are same in your equals method add

```
City temp = (City)obj;
return this.zip == temp.zip &&
       this.name == temp.name &&
       ...
;
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. Why use temp though? where did that come from/what does it mean?

Comment: it's from your code... `equals` takes object, to be able to compare you need to cast it to `City`

Answer (score -1):

eclipse auto-generates for you:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(latitude);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(longitude);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((state == null) ? 0 : state.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + zip;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        City other = (City) obj;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(latitude) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.latitude))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(longitude) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.longitude))
            return false;
        if (name == null)
        {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (state == null)
        {
            if (other.state != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!state.equals(other.state))
            return false;
        if (zip != other.zip)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If you're using Java 7, you could just call [`Objects.hashCode(this)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)). If not, use [`Arrays.hashCode(new Object[]{<every field in your class>})`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: Is it intentional that a latitude of +0.0 will be considered different from -0.0?